# Which partitions should I delete after removing Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

My laptop has two disks: Disk 0 is SSD (Windows) and Disk 1 is HDD (Data).
Then I created a partition (Partition 16 in the picture) to install Ubuntu in Disk 2.

A few days ago, I wanted to remove Ubuntu from my computer, so I cleaned the Partition 16. Now I need to reinstall Windows, I have cleaned the disk 0, but when I installed, there is an error:

> We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more
>   information, see the Setup log files.

I recognize that now there are 17 partitions in Disk 1. I think I could delete some of them, but I'm afraid that I would lost the data in Partition 1, 2 and 3. I'm so confused. And if I delete some of the partitions, can I install Windows successfully?

[Partitions_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6xZ5.jpg)

[Partitions_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxC0E.jpg)

[Partitions_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzpti.jpg)

[Partitions_4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eESm.jpg)

[List of volumes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaLeK.jpg)

[List of disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRUr3.jpg)

[List of partitions in disk 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R10Ne.jpg)

Please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: That partitioning scheme seems strange to me, but I admit that I'm not very familiar with Windows partitioning tools, and they seem cryptic to me. Can you please boot the system from an Ubuntu live-cd/usb and post the output of the following command? `sudo fdisk /dev/sd?` (the question mark `?` will be replaced by the shell with the letters of your disks).

Comment: If you cannot afford to loose your data you should back it up to another location. I assume you don’t have a working Windows. If that’s the case you can delete all the small partitions (those in MB in size) and leave the others alone (those in GB in size). You should then be able to install Windows. The partitions labelled Local Disk are probably the C: drive of old Windows installs. Once you have a fresh Windows install running you can look through them and copy any data that you want to keep

Comment: @gerlos This is what Ubuntu `sudo fdisk -l` shows:
[link](https://i.imgur.com/EDYnxHZ.jpg)

Comment: Thank you all for help me. I have deleted unnecessary partition in disk 1 and successfully installed Windows 10 on my machine.